# Gtk::Window* cannot be closed, Causes?

Tags: c++, glade, gtkmm

Why could be the causes of a Gtk::window cannot be closed?

I got a couple of misfuntion windows, they cannot be closed while the dialog whose create is still opened. Once the dialog whose opened that windows is closed, them can be closed normally ... is a strage behaviour.

In another version of the application, i was creating the windows in the same way, but from the main window and could be closed.

The main window is created in the main, the dialog is created in a class extended gtk::window and finally the two windows whose cannot be closed are created from the dialog.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <gtkmm/main.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Gnome::Gda::init();
    Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);

    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> refBuilder = Gtk::Builder::create_from_file("MainWindow.glade");

    MainWindow *window;

    refBuilder->get_widget_derived("window1", window);
    Gtk::Main::run(*window);

    return 0;
}
```

**MainWindow.cpp** -> class MainWindow : public Gtk::Window

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <libgdamm.h>
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>

#include "DBUtil.h"
#include "FormDialog.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(BaseObjectType* cobject, Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> refBuilder) :
 Gtk::Window(cobject),
 m_refBuilder(refBuilder) {
//stuff
}
//more stuff
   void MainWindow::on_button_new() {
   FormDialog *dialog;

   Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> refBuilder = Gtk::Builder::create_from_file("FormDialog.glade");

   refBuilder->get_widget_derived("dialog1", dialog);
   dialog->setConnectionData(cnc, parser);
   dialog->run();

   delete dialog;

}
//even more stuff
```

**FormDialog.cpp** -> class FormDialog : public Gtk::Dialog

#include "FormDialog.h"

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include "DBUtil.h"

FormDialog::FormDialog(BaseObjectType* cobject, Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> refBuilder) :
 Gtk::Dialog(cobject),
 m_refBuilder(refBuilder) {
 //stuff
}
//more stuff

int FormDialog::check_file(const char * path){
    if (strstr(path, ".jpg")!=NULL  || strstr(path, ".jpeg")!=NULL) 
    { return 1; }
    else {

Glib::ustring* us = new Glib::ustring("\n  Help \n");

Gtk::Window* help_win = new Gtk::Window(Gtk::WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
help_win->set_title ("Help");
help_win->move(15,55);
Gtk::Label* lab = new Gtk::Label(*us,false);

    help_win->add(*lab);
    help_win->show_all();
    return 0; }
 }
 //More stuff
 void FormDialog::on_button_sel() {
 //function stuff
 if (check_file(dialog.get_filename().c_str())) {
 //more function stuff

 }
```

Any hint/clue/fix would be appreciate! I can post the code if is needed. Thx in advance

Comment: Are the dialogs being opened with modal and/or transient set? A window cannot accept clicks if a child windows is blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Check your "FormDialog.glade", if your dialog has been set transient for the main window and has the property_modal on true, the main window can't be closed until the dialog exit first.